# Docker PHP permissions

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, fedora, grav

My php container does not have the permissions to write cache on the mounted volume.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
volumes:
    database_data:
        driver: local
services:
    php:
        build: ./docker/php/
        expose:
            - 9000
        volumes:
            - ./public:/var/www/html
        working_dir: /var/www/html
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        depends_on:
            - php
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        volumes_from:
            - php
```

docker/php/Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install json


# Permission fix
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
```

Comment: What permissions do the files in `./public` have? Does the `./public` contain all your files to run the app?

Comment: Having the exact error message log might help.

Comment: Check here https://github.com/krepysh-spec/lamp-docker-php-skeleton

Answer (score 8):

You need to adapt the uid & gif of www-data to match the ownership of the files.
Inside your php's Dockerfile:

```
RUN sed -ri 's/^www-data:x:82:82:/www-data:x:1000:50:/' /etc/passwd
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use it under Mac? Try to append this line in your php Dockerfile:
RUN usermod -G staff www-data

Comment: I am using Linux Fedora 25.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the chown flag when copying, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44766665/how-do-i-docker-copy-as-non-root).

```
COPY --chown=<user>:<group> ...
```